# MATLAB Code Sections - Script vs. Function

Tags: matlab, function, editor

When using Code Sections / Code Cells / Cell Mode (`%%`) in MATLAB R2014a and R2014b (see [these](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/improve-code-readability.html#brazeg3-1) [two](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html) MathWorks links), the section highlighting within the editor works fine with both scripts and functions.
However, the sections are shown correctly in the Details Panel of the Current Folder window **only for scripts and not for functions**, see the lower left corner in the following two screenshots:

[image: Section View in Current Folder is working for a Script]

[image: Section View in Current Folder is not working for a Function]

Is there a setting to change this behaviour? I do very much appreciate the section view in the Details Panel of the Current Folder window, as it shows the overall structure of the script and allows easy navigation, which I would like to get for functions as well.

Comment: I didn't even know this feature exists. -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently doesn't appear to be any way to customize the [Details Panel](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/01/19/the-data-is-in-the-details/) of the Current Folder browser. It shows you the underlying structure of a file in a way that is specific to the type of file. For [scripts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/scripts.html) it shows the section structure, since [sections](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html) are the only real way to partition a script.

For functions, partitioning of the code is generally accomplished by grouping operations into subfunctions, so the [local function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) structure in the file is shown (but [nested functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), for whatever reason, are not). Additionally, [class files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-components.html) will display object properties and methods, while  [MAT-files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/save-load-and-delete-workspace-variables.html) will display their variable contents.

Comment: I guess there's no way around it but to accept this fact. Thank you for your answer and feel free to submit this as a feature request if you think this might be a good idea, as I'm sure that you are a part of the MathWorks community.

Comment: I think the most annoying part of this is that nested functions do not appear in the details panel.